# How can i separate streambuilder's automatical setstate from my manual setstate in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am using a streambuilder for listening changes from firestore database and updating my widget. However my problem is i am using a few manual setstates to make visual changes in my code when a button is pressed and these setstates also triggers streambuilder's setstate and shows an extra loading screen to the users. How can i get seperate setstates? Should i use something else instead of streambuilder?

My code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'numbers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


Numbers myNumbers = Numbers();

void main(){
  runApp(
      GameScreen()
  );
}

class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id ='gamescreen';

  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  final _auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User loggedInUser;
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String collectionPath = 'users';
  String docPath;
  DocumentReference userdoc;


  void getCurrentUser() async{
    try{
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if(user !=null){
        loggedInUser =user;
        docPath = loggedInUser.uid;
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  Expanded attachNumber(imagenumber){
    return Expanded(
      child:FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[1]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage1'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[1] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[2]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage2'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[2] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[3]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage3'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[3] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[4]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage4'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[4] =true;
            }
          });
          final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
          assetsAudioPlayer.open(
            Audio("assets/audios/click.wav"),
          );
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Image.asset('images/$imagenumber'),
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton showDeleteNumbers(statusNumber,number){
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          myNumbers.numberStatus[statusNumber] =false;
          myNumbers.buttonValues[number] = 'nonumber.png';
        });
      },
      child: Image.asset('images/'+myNumbers.buttonValues['$number']),
    );
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userdoc = _firestore.collection(collectionPath).doc(docPath);
    if(_error) {
      return Text('error-game', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      return Text('Loading', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    }
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: userdoc.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          Map<String, dynamic> userDocument  = snapshot.data.data();
          print(collectionPath);
          print(docPath);
          print(snapshot.data);
          print(userDocument);
          return MaterialApp(
            home:Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                title: Text('Sayı Avı Oyun Ekranı'),
              ),
              body:Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 80,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getUserNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getOpponentNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex:10,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        showDeleteNumbers(1,'numberimage1'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(2,'numberimage2'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(3,'numberimage3'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(4,'numberimage4'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        attachNumber('one.png'),
                        attachNumber('two.png'),
                        attachNumber('three.png'),
                        attachNumber('four.png'),
                        attachNumber('five.png'),
                        attachNumber('six.png'),
                        attachNumber('seven.png'),
                        attachNumber('eight.png'),
                        attachNumber('nine.png'),
                        attachNumber('zero.png'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capturing the stream `userdoc.snapshots()` in a variable in initState instead of calling the snapshots method in every build.
That way you make sure that the streambuilder gets the same stream on every build and thus can maintain its state if you rebuild it